# How to add spinner in Jquery .html(<object data="http://example.com">)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I loading external website (my own) using Jquery.

```
<div id="siteloader"><center>
<img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="http://seafood.greenpeaceusa.org/images/spinner.gif" alt="Mountain View" /></center></div>
​
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#siteloader").html('<object "width:100%; height:2000px; data="http://example.com/findex.php">');
});
</scirpt>
```

As you can see right now, I am loading spinner gif inside the div and replacing the content of the div with the external website html, However it is replacing it on the moment it is downloading the website can I make it wait untill the website is downloaded and only then replace the html ?

By the way, .load method is not working for me for some reason =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `object` replaces content of the div at document.ready. It should be done when the object is loaded.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //$("#siteloader").html('<object "width:100%; height:2000px; data="http://example.com/findex.php">'); syntax errors here
   //this doesn't work as well
   $('<object "width:100%; height:2000px; data="http://example.com/findex.php">')
      .load(function(){
          $("#siteloader").empty().append(this);
      });
});
</script>
```

### Fixed working script:

```
    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    /*
    //wrong again spinner disappear before object loaded
    $('<object style="width:100%; height:400px; display:none;" data="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/helloworld.swf" />')
        .appendTo($("#siteloader"))
        .after(function () {
          console.log('loaded');
          $(this).show().siblings().each(function () {
              $(this).remove();
          });
      });
    */
        //and this work for sure
        var obj = document.createElement('object');
        obj.onload = function () {
            console.log('loaded');
            $(this).css({ width: '100%', height: '400px' }).show()
                .siblings().each(function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
        };
        obj.data = 'json.php';
        $(obj).appendTo('#siteloader');

});
    </script>
```

I hope it will work with your data as well. This looks ugly (mix jquery and pure JS) but this is the only found way to make it work. `$(obj).appendTo('#siteloader')` triggers the load.
Just in case, PHP used:

```
<?php
usleep(10000000);
echo '{"name":"qwas","qty":10,"curr":"'.date('h:i:s').'"}';
?>
```

Comment: I don't know why but this is not working ;( any ideas why ?

Comment: @DanielIliaguevHarta I just updated the last script tag (it was spelled "scirpt").  Maybe that will help?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill thank you but issue wasn't there. Fixed code added.